# Please, concretely, how to setup port forwarding to use remotely my iMac over SSH, with Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, imac

I have a Raspberry Pi and want to use remotely my iMac.

I am in another house, and want to use it over SSH. I have Termius too. I want to create a tunnel where the iMac connects to Raspberry Pi and I can then remotely use my iMac from my PC.

iMac => Raspberry Pi => My Computer

How can that be done?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far? There are a lot of guides regarding how to port forward and remote access. Also, what sort of connection is there between the two houses?

Comment: no connection at all

Comment: This is a duplicate of at least 2 other questions OP has asked over the past 2 or so days. One of his other questions is marked as a duplicate of this: https://superuser.com/questions/1834600/how-to-setup-port-forwardng-to-connect-ssh